# How to invoke android app remotely by using mobile device management?

Tags: android

I want to make an **app** which **will invoke from remote server** **[Admin panel]** and **lock the device** only admin can unlock the device.
So I just want to know how to invoke a command which will do lock and unlock for that device.

Comment: Is it possible still ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke app from remote servers. This is against Android architecture as it contains many security risks.

But you can for example create a file on the server that would be checked by app from device, and in case the file contains your command, your listeners can detect it and open your app (although not launch it, the app must be running in order to check url).

Comment: Well such apps for educational purpose for some specific requirement so i am working on it..may be FCM can help me out with this.